# YouTube Kids Block List Desktop

Tags: youtube, google-account, configuration

The YouTube Kids app currently has a feature that allows [blocking of specific videos and channels](https://support.google.com/youtubekids/answer/7178746).

I find this feature very useful, however from what I can tell the list can only be managed within the YouTube Kids app itself. The block list is definitely stored with the Google online account somehow - as I observe blocks from one device automatically applying to other devices signed into the same account.

Is it possible to view or modify list this in another location besides the YouTube Kids app - specifically a web location like many of the other account management services provided on google web? Ideally I could manage the list from my desktop web browser.

Comment: I don't believe you can change this on desktop in other places, however, you may want to [send feedback](https://support.google.com/youtubekids/answer/6130568?hl=en&ref_topic=6130504) if you want to see it implemented.

Comment: Yeah the only solution I can find for desktop is using [bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com) to just run the YouTube Kids app itself. Not quite the solution I was looking for, no different than using the app on a mobile.